# Issue launching web.py webserver from another directory

Tags: python, webserver, web.py, url-mapping

So I'm running web.py using the development server (not apache) and I'm having an issue running the webserver on startup.  The real issue is that I can only successfully run the webserver from its own directory.  The webserver launches and runs, but none of the static files are properly loaded.  So if my working directory is /home/user/webserver , then I can run code.py and the statics from /home/user/webserver/static load fine.  However, if I'm in /home/user directory, or any other directory, they won't load.  I know it's an issue of relative path names, but I don't believe I can just give the absolute path names of the static files as that would pose security risks and I don't believe web.py allows that.  I've been searching for a while for a solution, and I think it involves setting up a static file mapping from the url /static to the directory path to /home/pi/webserver/static, but I'm not sure how to do that.  Any help is greatly appreciated, or a link to an already answered question like this.  Thanks

Comment: typical pwd problem. try to write yourself a launching script and change pwd to proper directory before starting

Comment: If possible I'd like to have a more elegant solution (I feelt that the better way to handle is to make sure I can call the server from anywhere), but that's worth a shot

Comment: it's not working because your code relies on directory tree. it's your code that leads to this problem. having a launch script is elegant and permanent.

Comment: It definitely works!  It's a simple fix to do it your way so I'll just leave it.  I appreciate the help.